# MongoDb $elemMatch with $lookup variable

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization

I have a given MongoDb collection with documents which look similar to this:

```
{
items: [
  { id: 1, data: 'a' },
  { id: 2, data: 'b' },
  { id: 3, data: 'c' },
]
}
```

Now I have to `$lookup` from this collection. I need the array data from the element with id = 2 where id = 1 data matches the lookup value `$$value`. My first naive try to find the correct document looked like this:

```
$match {
  items: { $elemMatch: {
    id: 1,
    data: '$$value'
  } }
}
```

But the `$$value` is not evaluated, so the data is compared to the literal instead of its value. I also tried to evaluate the value using `$expr`, but I wasn't able to get the syntax right (if possible at all?).

The only working way I was able to get working was by extracting the data first and do the matching afterwards:

```
[
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data1: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$items', as: 'item',
                    cond: {$eq: ['$$item.id', 1]}
                }
            },
            data2: {
                $filter: {
                    input: '$items', as: 'item',
                    cond: {$eq: ['$$item.id', 2]}
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            data1: {$arrayElemAt: ['$data1.data', 0]},
            data2: {$arrayElemAt: ['$data2.data', 0]}
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {$eq: ['$data1', '$$value']}
        }
    }
];
```

But as one might expect, this approach is much slower. For the data involved the query took over 7s, whereas the upper approach (using a constant instead of a variable `$$value`) over 3x as fast.

Is it possible to use the variable `$$value` directly in the `$elemMatch` operator? Or is there any other optimization available to speed-up the collection lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first let's understand why your naive approach failed, Mongo's [pipelined lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) docs specify that:

> A $match stage requires the use of an $expr operator to access the variables. $expr allows the use of aggregation expressions inside of the $match syntax.

So the variable `value` that you are defining in the start of the `$lookup` is only accessible with the usage of [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), now also specified in the `$expr` docs:

> The arguments can be any valid aggregation expression

Sadly for us [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is not a "aggregation expression" as it belongs to the "query language". this is why your first approach failed. You are just not allowed to use `$elemMatch` within an `$expr` which is required in order to access the `$$value` field.

So what can we do?, well you can just use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as you already started doing:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection2",
      let: {
        value: "$data"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [
                {
                  $size: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$items",
                      as: "item",
                      cond: {
                        $and: [
                          {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$item.id",
                              1
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            $eq: [
                              "$$item.data",
                              "$$value"
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                0
              ],
              
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "res"
    }
  }
])
```

It would be easier to answer fully if you provide the full structure of both collections and the required end result as I had to guess some of the stuff here in order to write this pipeline.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PAmENOQqKkp)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Your demo structure is more than enough for my needs. If I could I would give another +1 for the Mongo Playground link!
Unfortunately, my updated query based on your solution was slower than my first approach ...

Comment: No problem, a constant value will always be the most efficient as it does not require any structure manipulation usage like `$filter`.